# Character to be escaped is missing with String.ReplaceAlli in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I have the following statements in a gradle file task but it gives the error 'Character to be escaped is missing' while executing it.

```
String contents = new File( 'settings/tomcat-config/catalina.bat' ).getText()
contents = contents.replaceAll('-Dappspace.home=[^\"]*','test');
```

Seems trivial but not been able to figure out the problem.

[image]

Comment: I guess you have to escape the backslash `-Dappspace.home=[^\\"]*`

Comment: Didn't work. Same error.

Comment: Do you want to write it back into the file? Or do you use the content somewhere else? And you don't have to escape `"` here try `contents.replaceAll(/-Dappspace.home=[^"]*/,'test')`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your catalina.bat file contains a line along the lines of:

```
set APP_HOME=-Dappspace.home="%CATALINA_BASE%\somedir"
```

then you would want to include the `"` in the match. In other words, running:

```
def contents = new File('catalina.bat').text
println contents.replaceAll('-Dappspace.home="([^"]+)"','test')
```

will print:

```
set APP_HOME=test
```

whereas running:

```
def contents = new File('catalina.bat').text
println contents.replaceAll(/(-Dappspace.home=")([^"]+)/, '$1test')
```

will print:

```
set APP_HOME=-Dappspace.home="test"
```

which I suspect is closer to what you want. If you want to replace the file contents you can just do:

```
def file = new File(...)
file.text = file.text.replaceAll(...)
```

also since this is in a gradle file, you can use the gradle dsl [project.file](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:file(java.lang.Object)) method and replace `new File(...)` with just `file(...)` in your code which gives us the final version (assuming you are looking at replacing the string in the file content):

```
def f = file('catalina.bat')
f.text = f.text.replaceAll(/(-Dappspace.home=")([^"]+)/, '$1test')
```